Problem with OpenSSL and Memgraph on Rhel 8
I've taken CentOS7 RMP packet and I've tried to install Memgraph on a box running RHEL 8.
I've encountered the SSL related error. Is there a way to get this working?
memgraph[13859]: /usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or direct>
systemd[1]: memgraph.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
systemd[1]: memgraph.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


Red Hat 8 and CentOS 8 are not officially supported. You can try running the following two commands to fix the issue that you have:
sudo dnf install compat-openssl10
sudo systemctl restart memgraph

